# SDL deployement on MacOS

Tags: deployment, sdl

I have developped an application using *SDL2* installed through *brew*. It runs fine on my development environment but when trying to launch it on another machine I have the following error:

```
Drivers count: 2
Driver name: opengl
Driver name: software
Initialize all SDL subsystems
Set up the window
exists true
failed to load  "/Users/joker/Desktop/SDLTest.app/Contents/MacOS/look.png"
Failed loading libpng.dylib: dlopen(libpng.dylib, 6): image not found
```

Here is my output when typing `otool -L SDLTest.app/Contents/MacOS/SDLTest` :

```
SDLTest.app/Contents/MacOS/SDLTest:
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/libSDL2_ttf-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.2.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.1)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.1)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.3.0, current version 5.3.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

Here is my output when typing `otool -L SDLTest.app/Frameworks/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib` :

```
SDLTest.app/Contents/Frameworks/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib:
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

Here is the content of my `SDLTest.app/Contents/Frameworks` folder:

```
total 3064
drwxr-xr-x  14 martin  staff   476B 27 oct 15:11 .
drwxr-xr-x   7 martin  staff   238B 27 oct 15:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 martin  staff   136B 27 oct 15:11 QtCore.framework
drwxr-xr-x   4 martin  staff   136B 27 oct 15:11 QtGui.framework
drwxr-xr-x   4 martin  staff   136B 27 oct 15:11 QtPrintSupport.framework
drwxr-xr-x   4 martin  staff   136B 27 oct 15:11 QtWidgets.framework
drwxr-xr-x   6 martin  staff   204B 27 oct 15:11 SDL2.framework
drwxr-xr-x   7 martin  staff   238B 27 oct 15:11 SDL2_image.framework
drwxr-xr-x   7 martin  staff   238B 27 oct 15:11 SDL2_ttf.framework
-rw-r--r--   1 martin  staff   755K 27 oct 15:11 libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 martin  staff    78K 27 oct 15:11 libSDL2_image-2.0.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 martin  staff    33K 27 oct 15:11 libSDL2_ttf-2.0.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 martin  staff   491K 27 oct 15:11 libfreetype.6.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 martin  staff   164K 27 oct 15:11 libpng16.16.dylib
```

Comment: Did you run `otool -L` on the app to see dependencies ?

Comment: Yes and I don't see anythink but I will update my question with *otool* output

Comment: I assume you mean when you try to run it on a different machine. Did you make sure you packaged the additional frameworks and libraries with your application? If not how do you expect it to run on another machine which may not have them installed...

Comment: @Zammalad I just add the content of my framework folder. As you can see the *libpng* library is embedded in the bundle.

Comment: Did you bundle all the resources too. The error states it can't load a file because it can't find it. Is it definitely in the location it is looking for it. You should have a read of this - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @Zammalad After reading the article, I don't undertand why there is no dependency between *SDL2_image* and *libpng*...

Comment: @MartinDelille Not really sure what you are saying. Anyway, why are you including all of those libraries? If you bundle the framework they aren't required.

Comment: @Zammalad The bundle is done with the `macdeployqt` tool. I try to learn what this tool do in details.

Comment: The problem here is that SDL2_image doesn't link against the libpng16.16.dylib library in a way that otool will notice.  Instead it directly calls dlopen("libpng.dylib") in its code, when png reading facilities are required.  So first issue is that otool/install_name_tool are useless here.  Second issue is that it's not looking for the libpng16.16.dylib that you've bundled (presumably resolved via homebrew's symlinks), so even if it *was* looking in the right place (which it's not), it *still* wouldn't find a library with the name it's looking for.